# UITableViewCell separator line disappeared under the UIImage into cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

Trying to add an UIImage into default UITableViewCell. The image was appeared, but part of separator line (under the image) became disappeared. How can I fix that?

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]         initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.textLabel.text = @"text";
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"];
```

That's how it looks like now - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTOQF.png)

Comment: If you have created your tableView in the interface builder then check the value of separator attribute in the attributes inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add this line of code after you instantiate de UITableView:

```
[_tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
```

If this doesn't work, I suggest that you execute the app on a real device. I have had a similar problem some days ago, and the problem was with the iOS simulator...

I hope this helps!